# Debug node project (botpress)

Tags: node.js, chatbot

I'm tring debug my [botpress](https://github.com/botpress/botpress/tree/develop/x) project. Debugs it's working, but only showing one file to me, not all the project files.

I'm use Google Chrome DevTool to debug the code, this is showing to me:

[image]

And this is my project with file to show.

[image]

All code: https://github.com/luizcarvalho/chatfuel

I need to show: `src/actions.js`, `src/index.js` and `src/renderers.js` to can debug my project.

Answer (score 5):

I added `const actions = require('./src/actions');` in `botfile.js` and works!

[image]